# Why cannot do (A)o, but (o as A) is fine when debugging generic in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, generics, visual-studio-code

Say I have a generic class and some other code as below:

```cs
public class S<T>
{
    public void Method1(T o)
    {
    }
}

public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static void Test()
{
    var s = new S<A>();
    var a = new A() { Name = "John" };
    s.Method1(a);
}
```

When **debugging** `s.Method1(a)` and stepping into `S<T>.Method1(T o)`, I found that I cannot evaluate the cast operation - `(GenericRuntimeCastWhenDebugging.A)o` in the `DEBUG CONSOLE` when using **VSCode** or in the `Immediate` window when using **VS2017**, it gives error:

> (GenericRuntimeCastWhenDebugging.A)o
>
> error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'T' to 'GenericRuntimeCastWhenDebugging.A'

but `(o as GenericRuntimeCastWhenDebugging.A)` works fine in this case and shows the result:

> (o as GenericRuntimeCastWhenDebugging.A)
>
> {GenericRuntimeCastWhenDebugging.A}

I would expect that in this case `(GenericRuntimeCastWhenDebugging.A)o` should also work fine! Anyone knows why?

***Edit:***
I understand that `T o` isn't allowed be casted to `A` by `(A)o` at compile time in the example I gave, and the difference between `(A)o` and `(o as A)` in C#. I was interested that **during debugging** the 1st way to cast `(GenericRuntimeCastWhenDebugging.A)o` **raises error**, but the 2nd way to cast `(o as GenericRuntimeCastWhenDebugging.A)` **casts successfully** and returns as the right `A` object back. So **during debugging**, running `(o as GenericRuntimeCastWhenDebugging.A).Name` in the `DEBUG CONSOLE` is also fine and does return value: `John`.

> (o as GenericRuntimeCastWhenDebugging.A).Name
>
> "John"

Further, turned out that at compile time i can actually write the following code, it runs fine and `n2` is set to `John`. Don't need a trick like boxing/unboxing.

```cs
public class S<T>
{
    public void Method1(T o)
    {
        // var n1 = ((A)o).Name; Cannot compile
        var n2 = (o as A).Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with the debugger really. The same expressions would compile (or not) if you wrote them inside of Method1.

Comment: Question is why do you worry about it? You are not going to write such code ever, because that would not be a Generic anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there are no explicit conversions defined for `T -> A`. This is because there is *no constraint* on your generic type. Using `as` works because it's explicitly asking whether or not `o` can be cast, as opposed to explictly *saying* that `o` can be cast.

You can restrict `T` to be either `A` or a subclass/implementation of `A` with the following.

```
public class S<T> where T : A
{
    public void Method1(T o)
    {
        var a = (A)o;
    }
}
```

This is now valid, as the compiler is satisfied this won't generate a run-time exception.

Alternatively, you could write:

```
public class S<T>
{
    public void Method1(T o)
    {
        var a = (A)(object)o;
    }
}
```

Which will compile, because anything<sup>1</sup> is castable (or boxable) to an `object`, and you can cast (or unbox) an `object` to any type. Note however, this is probably a bad idea, as there's nothing stopping someone from writing `new S<int>().Method1(5)`

<sup>1 Anything is (un)boxable/(un)castable at compile time - this does not however, protect you from runtime exceptions.</sup>

Comment: It's not entirely true that someone can unbox to any type, you can only unbox to the true underlying type, which is why you sometimes see code like `(long)(int)myObject`.

Comment: This is a great explanation, thank you! And the assignment in your last example could be wrapped in an `if (o is A){...}`

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Sorry, I should have clarified; you can *compile* any cast/unbox. Obviously, specifying an invalid type will result in a runtime exception. I'll update the post to be clearer

Comment: @Rob It's not limited to invalid types, unboxing can only go back to the true underlying type. As in my example above, a `long` can successfully represent an `int`, but would still fail if you simply did `(long)myBoxedInt`. But yes you are correct about it being fine at compile time, I wasn't very clear on that either :-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Well, it *is* an invalid type.. `(long)(int)myObject` unboxes and then *converts* (rather than casts) to a `long`. `(long)myObject` would be attempting to unbox into an invalid type, assuming `myObject` is a boxed `int`

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference in return value between `(A)o` and `o as A`.

`(A)o` is *casting*. If it fails, throws exception and everything crashes. Here you are basically asserting that `o` must be of type `A`. When it is not, BOOM.

`o as A` is much more gentle. It does not go BOOM! when it fails to convert `o` to type `A`. It just evaluates to `null`. You can then check whether the conversion failed by checking the return value. However, this only works on reference types because value types can't have `null` values.

Edit:

Actually, `(A)o` can't even compile. The compiler thinks that 9 times out of 10, this conversion is gonna fail, so it does not even allow it. I don't know how did you get that to compile and see the error in the debug console.

Comment: @Rob It's not a run-time issue. You can't compile (A)o code. It will give error 'Cannot convert type T to A'.

Comment: @niksofteng But since the OP saw it in the debug console, it is a runtime issue. And who is Rob?

Comment: @Sweeper I left an incorrect comment (and quickly removed it) - but unfortunately not quickly enough ;)

Comment: You use `as`. You can probably do something like `A a = o as A;` then check whether `a` is null. If it is not, do whatever you want with it. @RufusL

Comment: @RufusL Wait, are you and the OP the same person? Why are you thanking me?